# Reading kernel information in Linux with C/C++

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel

It happens sometimes that I need to retrieve some system data like CPU usage, process information etc.. which I commonly find in /proc/.... What I do from C/C++ is to read the correct file in /proc/..., parse it and get the information. This is quite bothering and somehow to be kernel version dependent. Is this the correct way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Linux kernel doesn't offer any system calls which can be used to retrieve the kind of system information that's exposed via `/proc`. Your best bet in that case is to keep using that file system.

If it makes you feel any better, all the tools like `top`, `ps` or `htop` all use the `/proc` filesystem. You should check out their sources if you're having trouble with using it.

Comment: I don't know why but I really don't like it this way. Anyway, thanks!